# How to make realistic plane movement in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

My current plane movement is ok for the first iteration except I cannot get around on how to make a effective roll movement. What I need is when you pitch up using up arrow on a bank is to make it pitch in the same direction of the angle your banked at. Ignore Propeller variable it is for something im working on later.

Heres my code

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class movement : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject plane;
public Rigidbody rb;
public float thrust = 100f;
public GameObject propeller;

void Update()
{

    if (Input.GetKey("left"))
    {
        plane.transform.Rotate(0, 0, 1, Space.World);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("right"))
    {
        plane.transform.Rotate(0, 0, -1, Space.World);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("space"))
    {
        rb.AddForce(transform.forward * thrust);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftControl))
    {
        rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        rb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("down"))
    {
        plane.transform.Rotate(-1, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
    if (Input.GetKey("up"))
    {
        plane.transform.Rotate(1, 0, 0, Space.World);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to see this link https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.AddTorque.html.

It helped me to learn how to make a rolling ball in a project for school.

Adding torque will create an equivalent of an linear movement for round object.

Here an exemple

`rb.AddTorque("the force in the x axis", the force in the y-axis, "the force int the z axis,"the force mode")`

Comment: It did not work as all I got is errors and when I got it to go into play mode the code did nothing